# How do channel views work on YouTube on the about page?

Tags: youtube

If you go to pewdiepie's channel and go to the about section, under stats, it says his channel has 26,744,991,608 views, even though this is above the world population. How do the channel views work?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This number denotes the total number of views across all videos. So if pewdiepie has 4,275 videos on his channel and 26,755,673,535 total views, that's on average 6,258,637 views per video.